# Remove stylesheets from Campaign Monitor plugin

Tags: functions, wp-enqueue-style

I am trying to disable the styles being loaded for the [Campaign Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/forms-for-campaign-monitor/) plugin for Wordpress so I can style them myself.

The code in the plugin that seems to be responsible for loading the stylesheet is:

```
public static function loadPublicScripts()
 {
    $plugins_url = plugins_url('forms-for-campaign-monitor');

    wp_enqueue_script(Helper::tokenize('ajax-script-public'), $plugins_url . '/forms/views/public/js/app.js', array(), false,true);
    wp_register_style(Helper::tokenize('custom_cm_monitor_css'), $plugins_url . '/forms/views/public/css/app.css', false, '1.0.0');
    wp_enqueue_style(Helper::tokenize('custom_cm_monitor_css') );

    // in JavaScript, object properties are accessed as ajax_object.ajax_url, ajax_object.we_value
    wp_localize_script(Helper::tokenize('ajax-script-public'), 'ajax_request', array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
    ));
}
```

I was assuming a simple `wp_deregister_style('custom_cm_monitor_css');` or `wp_dequeue_style('custom_cm_monitor_css');` would solve that issue but it doesn't seem to be working.

Does anyone have any insight into removing the styling?

Comment: What is `Helper::tokenize()` doing? Maybe it is modifying the handles...

Comment: It may actually be appending the plugin name to the call. The outputted link to the stylesheet is `<link rel='stylesheet' id='forms-for-campaign-monitor-custom_cm_monitor_css-css'  href='http://website.com/wp-content/plugins/forms-for-campaign-monitor/forms/views/public/css/app.css?ver=1.0.0' type='text/css' media='all' />`

Comment: I figured it was doing something like that. You will need to use the same handles when deregistering and dequeueing, e.g. `forms-for-campaign-monitor-custom_cm_monitor_css`.

Comment: I did try a few variants to deregister or dequeue the script and none seemed to work.

`remove_action( 'wp_register_style', 'forms-for-campaign-monitor-custom_cm_monitor_css-css' );`
`remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_style', 'forms-for-campaign-monitor-custom_cm_monitor_css-css' );`
`wp_deregister_style( 'forms-for-campaign-monitor-custom_cm_monitor_css-css' );`
`wp_dequeue_style( 'forms-for-campaign-monitor-custom_cm_monitor_css-css' );`
None of them seemed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string for the handle is `custom_cm_monitor_css` but it is passed to `Helper::tokenize()` which turns it into `forms-for-campaign-monitor-custom_cm_monitor_css`. Note that the ID of the stylesheet in the page source shows `forms-for-campaign-monitor-custom_cm_monitor_css-css` but the ending `-css` is appended by WordPress.

So, we need to dequeue the style with the handle:

```
forms-for-campaign-monitor-custom_cm_monitor_css
```

This needs to happen later than it is enqueued. It is not clear when `loadPublicScripts` is hooked from original question, so we'll just do it really late. After that, we enqueue our own styles.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_campaign_monitor_styles', 9999 );
function wpse_campaign_monitor_styles() {
    // Dequeue Campaign Monitor styles.
    wp_dequeue_style( 'forms-for-campaign-monitor-custom_cm_monitor_css' );

    // Deregister Campaign Monitor styles. (Dequeing should be enough to stop it from being loaded though.)
    wp_deregister_style( 'forms-for-campaign-monitor-custom_cm_monitor_css' )

    // Enqueue custom Campaign Monitor styles located in:
    // {theme-or-child-theme-name}/css/wpse-campaign-monitor.css
    wp_enqueue_style(
       'wpse_campaign_monitor_styles',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/wpse-campaign-monitor.css'
    );
}
```

*This code had not been tested.*

Comment: Thanks Dave, that worked. As you mentioned I think just using `wp_dequeue_style` was enough to remove that script from the queue in combination with the function and `add_action`. Does the `9999` at the end of `add_action` denote when it is triggered in relation to the other actions?

Comment: Glad to hear @tylorreimer! The `9999` is the priority of the hook. It is applicable to all callbacks assigned to the *same action or filter* (in this case the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action). Lower numbers fire earlier than higher numbers (negative numbers are valid too). The default is `10`. When removing a hook via `remove_action` or `remove_filter` the same priority must be used as when the hook was added.